Comparing Performance: Python/JavaScript vs. Rust for Solana API Interaction
I am exploring the performance differences between Python/JavaScript and Rust when interacting with the Solana blockchain. I understand that Rust, being a low-level language without a garbage collector, generally offers faster execution speeds compared to Python and JavaScript. However, I'm curious about the practical performance implications in the context of Solana.
Specifically, I would like to know:
How significant is the performance difference when using Rust (with libraries like solders) compared to Python (solana.py) and JavaScript (web3.js) for Solana?
Are there any crucial performance differences that are particularly noticeable in certain operations or scenarios when interacting with Solana?
If anyone has experience using both Rust and either Python or JavaScript for Solana applications, I would appreciate your insights on where the performance really makes a difference.

If you're interacting with RPC, the biggest performance bottleneck will be the networking aspect, waiting for the RPC node to return data, and the performance differences between languages will be negligible.
